# rails showing wrong version event updating command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just updated rails via command

```
$ sudo gem update --system
$ sudo gem install rails
```

I can see gem list

```
rails (3.2.3, 3.0.1)
```

but on terminal when I type `rails --version` its giving me version `3.0.1`, How to use 3.2.3?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sudo` to perform any gem tasks, as that is updating the system version of Ruby, which is probably not what you want to do.

I would recommend using RVM to set up your Ruby installation and then installing Rails using just `gem install rails`.

If you're using Ubuntu then I have [a guide for that](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) and I also have one for [Mac OS X](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/06/mac-os-x-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) too.

Comment: what about those of us who can't install RVM....like those of us being hosted by hostmonster